# How can I [increase the rate limits/ batch requests] for the Google Vertex AI Bison API?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm testing out google palm API to recursively summarize a long text, and have since come into rate-limiting issues and therefore some questions to verify on.

It seems that the number of requests made to the bison API is 60/min (this seems quite low).

1. Is there a way to batch the requests made to the bison API? And will that allow me to make more inference per second?
2. Is there a way to increase the rate limits? 60/min seems too low and not fit for production usage.

Thanks!

I tried looking into these documents:

1.[Rate limit documents](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas):
[Table for rate limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHCrv.png)

2.[Increasing rate limits](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/view_manage#requesting_higher_quota) but it seems like it's not meant for the bison model

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make batch requests to text-bison. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/text/batch-prediction-genai The linked document describes how to prepare you batch inputs and invoke a batch request.

You can also submit a batch request as part of a Vertex--AI pipeline job https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/generative_ai/batch_eval_llm.ipynb

2. You can request a quota increase in your project. The name of the quota in this case is "Online prediction requests per base model per minute per region per base_model" and you would request a quota change for the region and model of interest. e.g. us-central1, text-bison